# Update programs of BSD to latest

Tags: bash

The programs of BSD in MacOS are not upgrated to the latest

Take examples:

> man ls
>   BSD              May 19, 2002              BSD
>
> V.S.
>
> FreeBSD   11.1    December    1, 2015           FreeBSD 11.1

And

> man find
>
> BSD                           September 28, 2011                           BSD
>
> V.S.
>
> FreeBSD    11.1               January 24, 2017           FreeBSD 11.1

and so on

How to update them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD, BSD and macOS is not the same.

The updates for macOS system utilities come from Apple and are included in both major and minor system upgrades for macOS that you install using the App Store.

There's no need to update these utilities through other means.

If you want *other* programs than the Apple-supplied ones, you can install for example Homebrew that allows you to install alternatives. Keep in mind though that even though two utilities might have the same name across different operating systems, they are not necessarily the same program. That is "tar" is not the same on FreeBSD as on macOS as on Linux (etc).